# Laravel 10 helper function curl function post method is not working

Tags: php, curl, helper, laravel-10

I have created the app/Helper/healper.php file create then defined the cURL request function.

```
function curlRequest($api_name, $api_url, $method, $requestdata){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => env('API_BASE_URL').$api_url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($requestdata),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if (＄err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . ＄err;
    } else {
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }
}
```

Then getting errors like.

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> GET, HEAD. in file

We are multiple trying then first create app/Helper/helpers.php file then after defining in the composer.json file like

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        **"files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]**
    }
```

After run command: `composer dump-autoload`

Then check in please check my steps and any missing or wrong step define then let me know.

Comment: app/Helper/healper.php or app/Helpers/helpers.php? You have two conflicting paths.

Comment: Also, modify your cURL request to include the correct content type for JSON data:

CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
),

Comment: The error means the route method in your laravel router file is not matched. Your router may define a get method, but you use post to access that router.

Comment: You should always use the HTTP facade in Laravel instead of using cURL https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client